# perl sort substrings using array to determine collating sequence

Tags: perl, sorting, collate

I have a list of strings of the form:

```
CLUB1_20201008_EVE
CLUB1_20201008_AFT
CLUB1_20201008_AM
CLUB1_20201008_AM2
CLUB1_20201008_PM
CLUB1_20201008_NIGHT
CLUB2_20201008_EVE
CLUB2_20201008_AFT
CLUB2_20201008_AM
CLUB2_20201008_AM2
CLUB2_20201008_PM
CLUB2_20201008_NIGHT
```

I can get the sort to work by club name and date but the time of day needs to be sorted like `AM,AM2,AFT,PM,EVE,NIGHT`. These are obviously unsortable since their sequence is not alphabetical.

How do I use an auxiliary array to get them to sort in the proper order?

Thanks,Milt

Expected Output
CLUB1_20201008_NIGHT
CLUB2_20201008_NIGHT
CLUB1_20201008_EVE
CLUB2_20201008_EVE
CLUB1_20201008_PM
CLUB2_20201008_PM
CLUB1_20201008_AFT
CLUB2_20201008_AFT
CLUB1_20201008_AM2
CLUB2_20201008_AM2
CLUB1_20201008_AM
CLUB2_20201008_AM

Comment: Can you show the expected output?

Answer (score 3):

One way is to use a hash table that maps the strings to their numerical order, and then comparing based on that:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw/say state/;

my @clubs = qw/CLUB1_20201008_EVE CLUB1_20201008_AFT CLUB1_20201008_AM
CLUB1_20201008_AM2 CLUB1_20201008_PM CLUB1_20201008_NIGHT
CLUB2_20201008_EVE CLUB2_20201008_AFT CLUB2_20201008_AM
CLUB1_20201008_AM2 CLUB1_20201008_PM CLUB1_20201008_NIGHT/;

sub sort_clubs {
    state $mappings = { AM => 1, AM2 => 2, AFT => 3, PM => 4,
                        EVE => 5, NIGHT => 6 };

    # For use with a Schwartzian Transform of the original data.
    # Expected format of arguments: [ [ club name, date, time ], original string ]
    my $cmp = $a->[0][0] cmp $b->[0][0];
    if ($cmp != 0) {
        return $cmp;
    }
    $cmp = $a->[0][1] <=> $b->[0][1];
    if ($cmp != 0) {
        return $cmp;
    } else {
        return $mappings->{$a->[0][2]} <=> $mappings->{$b->[0][2]}
    }
}

@clubs = map { $_->[1] } sort sort_clubs map { [ [ split(/_/, $_) ], $_ ] } @clubs;
say "@clubs";
```

---

Wikipedia has information on the [Schwartzian Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) if you haven't seen that idiom for sorting before.

Comment: ST? bah. [GRT](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=145659)! :) Seriously, though, both ST and GRT are probably overkill, adding unnecessary complexity here. (There's a GRT-based solution in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64494974/589924), but it's not the one I recommend.)

Answer (score 3):

The trick is to create a map between each time-of-day string and a number you can sort.

```perl
my @shifts = qw( AM AM2 AFT PM EVE NIGHT );
my %shift_order = map { $shifts[$_] => $_ } 0..$#shifts;
```

Solutions based on [Sort-Key](https://metacpan.org/release/Sort-Key) will be among the cleanest and fastest.

```perl
use Sort::Key::Multi qw( ssukeysort );

my @shifts = qw( AM AM2 AFT PM EVE NIGHT );
my %shift_order = map { $shifts[$_] => $_ } 0..$#shifts;

my @sorted =
   ssukeysort {
      my ($club, $date, $shift) = split /_/;
      ( $club, $date, $shift_order{$shift} )
   }
      @unsorted;
```

---

Simple solution without modules:

```perl
my @shifts = qw( AM AM2 AFT PM EVE NIGHT );
my %shift_order = map { $shifts[$_] => $_ } 0..$#shifts;

my @sorted =
   sort {
      my ($club_a, $date_a, $shift_a) = split /_/, $a;
      my ($club_b, $date_b, $shift_b) = split /_/, $b;

      $club_a cmp $club_b
         or
      $date_a cmp $date_b
         or
      $shift_order{$shift_a} <=> $shift_order{$shift_b}
   }
      @unsorted;
```

Performant solution without modules:

```perl
my @shifts = qw( AM AM2 AFT PM EVE NIGHT );
my %shift_order = map { $shifts[$_] => $_ } 0..$#shifts;

my @sorted =
   map { ( split /\0/ )[-1] }
      sort
         map {
            my ($club, $date, $shift) = split /_/;
            join("\0", $club, $date, $shift_order{$shift}, $_)
         }
            @unsorted;
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many possible ways to achieve desired result.

Note: code assumed based that you do not try to sort on club, date_hour_min and day_time at once as it not declared in your question. A sample of desired sorted output would be helpful for clearance of your problem -- we can not read what is on your mind.

Please research following two possible approaches.

You declared sort order based on *time day* index in the strings -- lets put it to use in some way. I will use `AM,AM2,AFT,PM,EVE,NIGHT` as initialization string for simplicity.

First approach utilizes `%order` hash with *time day* be a key and digit representing numerical order. Strings stored in HoA with numerical order as a key. Once you filled the hash just print according numerical key order with lines preserving order of their appearance on input.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $count = 0;
my @set   = split ',', 'AM,AM2,AFT,PM,EVE,NIGHT';
my %order = map { $_ => $count++ } @set;
my %result;

while( <DATA> ) {
    chomp;
    for my $k ( keys %order ) {
        push @{$result{$order{$k}}}, $_ if /_$k\z/;
    }
}

for( sort {$a <=> $b} keys %result ) {
    say for @{ $result{$_} };
}


__DATA__
CLUB1_20201008_EVE
CLUB1_20201008_AFT
CLUB1_20201008_AM
CLUB1_20201008_AM2
CLUB1_20201008_PM
CLUB1_20201008_NIGHT
CLUB2_20201008_EVE
CLUB2_20201008_AFT
CLUB2_20201008_AM
CLUB1_20201008_AM2
CLUB1_20201008_PM
CLUB1_20201008_NIGHT
```

Output

```
CLUB1_20201008_AM
CLUB2_20201008_AM
CLUB1_20201008_AM2
CLUB1_20201008_AM2
CLUB1_20201008_AFT
CLUB2_20201008_AFT
CLUB1_20201008_PM
CLUB1_20201008_PM
CLUB1_20201008_EVE
CLUB2_20201008_EVE
CLUB1_20201008_NIGHT
CLUB1_20201008_NIGHT
```

Second approach is even more simple. Push the lines in HoA `%result` based on *time day* index (at the end of the line). Then print print HoA according predefined `$order` array.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my @order = split ',', 'AM,AM2,AFT,PM,EVE,NIGHT';
my %result;

while( <DATA> ) {
    chomp;
    push @{$result{$1}}, $_ if /_([^_]+)\z/;
}

for( @order ) {
    say for @{ $result{$_} };
}


__DATA__
CLUB1_20201008_EVE
CLUB1_20201008_AFT
CLUB1_20201008_AM
CLUB1_20201008_AM2
CLUB1_20201008_PM
CLUB1_20201008_NIGHT
CLUB2_20201008_EVE
CLUB2_20201008_AFT
CLUB2_20201008_AM
CLUB1_20201008_AM2
CLUB1_20201008_PM
CLUB1_20201008_NIGHT
```

Output

```
CLUB1_20201008_AM
CLUB2_20201008_AM
CLUB1_20201008_AM2
CLUB1_20201008_AM2
CLUB1_20201008_AFT
CLUB2_20201008_AFT
CLUB1_20201008_PM
CLUB1_20201008_PM
CLUB1_20201008_EVE
CLUB2_20201008_EVE
CLUB1_20201008_NIGHT
CLUB1_20201008_NIGHT
```